# Partial derivatives wrt input and weights in CNNs

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, image-processing

I'm working on understanding the backpropagation process in convolutional neural networks (CNNs) and am having some trouble comprehending how to calculate the partial derivatives of the output of a CNN layer with respect to both the input (x) and the filter weights (W). Specifically, I'm looking at a simple 1D convolution scenario with an input that has 2 channels and a single filter that spans both channels.

Given:

- The input (x[n]) has dimensions (\mathbb{R}^{2 \times n}), with 2 channels.
- The filter (W) applied by the layer has dimensions (\mathbb{R}^{1 \times 2 \times 3}), indicating it is a single filter spanning 2 channels, with a kernel size of 3.
- The convolution operation reduces the input to an output (O) with dimensions (\mathbb{R}^{1 \times 2}), indicating a single output channel with a spatial dimension of 2, calculated with a stride of 2 and no padding.

Questions:

1. Partial derivative with respect to (W): How do you determine the dimension of (\frac{\partial f_W(x)}{\partial W}) and provide an expression for the values of this derivative? I understand that this derivative should have the same dimensions as (W), but I'm unclear on how to express its values in terms of the input (x) and the operation performed.
2. Partial derivative with respect to (x): Similarly, how is the dimension of (\frac{\partial f_W(x)}{\partial x}) determined, and what would be an expression for the values of this derivative? Given the operation reduces the input's dimension, how does this affect the calculation and interpretation of the gradient with respect to (x)?

I've looked through various resources but still find the transition from the theory to the actual computation of these gradients a bit complex. Any insights, explanations, or references to materials that could help understand these would be greatly appreciated!